# Create trigger on update column in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I try to create trigger before table is updated. I want to it works when two specific columns are changed: status and sale_profit columns. If one of these columns is updated, trigger must set is_changed column's value to 1. But the below code gives me error like this:

**Error:**

```
 MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax ... syntax use near at line 7
```

**SQL code:**

```
 CREATE  TRIGGER  updateIsChanged
    BEFORE UPDATE  ON manage_product
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF NEW.`status` <> OLD.`status` || NEW.sale_profit <> OLD.sale_profit
    then
     SET NEW.is_changed = 1;


    END IF;
    END
```

Comment: || ? Try changing to or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I solved my problem by adding **delimiter** to beginning and end of the code.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
delimiter $$
CREATE  TRIGGER  updateIsChanged
BEFORE UPDATE  ON manage_product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`status` <> OLD.`status` || NEW.sale_profit <> OLD.sale_profit THEN
        SET NEW.is_changed = 1;
END IF;
END$$
```